# Changing a variable to constant after declaration

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects:

```
List<ConTri> triListOrig;
```

Which are read into the program from a text file. Once these objects are read in I don't want the values to be changed. (At the moment something is changing them but I cant find what). Is there any way I can programmatically set the objects to constants/ make them unchangeable after they have been read into the file?

Comment: You're looking for `ReadOnlyCollection` or the immutable collections package.

Comment: @SLaks, You should probably make that an answer, perhaps with an example of use

Comment: Thanks, For anyone else this is helpful http://www.dotnetperls.com/readonlycollection

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working. The values in the `ReadOnlyCollection` are still being changed.